# Увеличение очков до следующего уровня

Tags: python, алгоритм

пишу мини игру на python, есть небольшая проблемка, не могу решить. У меня сейчас разница между всеми уровнями стоит 100 очков. Как сделать так, чтобы каждый раз при достижении уровня очки до след уровня увеличивались на 100 очков? Например 1ур - 100 очков, 2ой уровень - 200 очков, а уже до третьего уровня было 400 очков.

```
user_score = int(input('Enter your score: '))
level = 0
need_score = 100


while user_score > 0:
    if user_score >= 100:
        user_score -= need_score
        level += 1
        print('your level is: ', level)
        if user_score < 100:
            remain_score = need_score - user_score
            print('to next level need: ', remain_score)
            break
    else:
        level += 1
        remain_score = need_score - user_score
        print('your level is: ', level)
        print('to next level need: ', remain_score)
        break
```

Comment: `Количество_очков = (2 ** Номер_текущего_уровня) * 100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы вообще работал только с количеством очков пользователя, из которых можно и уровень вычислить и оставшееся очки до следующего уровня (то есть, очки пользователя просто накапливаются). Исходя из расчета, что между 0 и 1 уровнем - 100 очков, 1 и 2 - 200, 2 и 3 - 400  и т. д.:

```
import math

user_score = 561

def get_level(score):
    level = int(math.log2(score//100))
    next_level_points = (2**level*100)
    points_left = 2**(level+1)*100 - score
    return level, next_level_points, points_left

res = get_level(user_score)
print(f"User level:{res[0]}\nTotal points to gain next level:{res[1]}\nPoints left to next level:{res[2]}")
```

Получим:

```
User level:2
Total points to gain next level:400
Points left to next level:239
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
user_score = int(input('Enter your score: '))
level = 0
need_score = 100


while user_score > 0:
    if user_score >= need_score: 
        user_score -= need_score
        level += 1
        print('your level is: ', level)
        if level %3 == 0:
            need_score += 200

        else:
            need_score += 100

     if user_score < 100:
            remain_score = need_score - user_score
            print('to next level need: ', remain_score)
            break
     else:
            level += 1
            remain_score = need_score - user_score
            print('your level is: ', level)
            print('to next level need: ', remain_score)
            break
```